# Moments of discrete Asset Price Model

Tags: brownian-motion, finance-mathematics, asset-pricing

Say if B is standard Brownian motion then:

$S(t) = S0e^{((- σ^2)/2)t+σB(t)}$

The mean of this SDE would be

$[()]=_0^{}$

I know to do this you use the density function and integrate by parts twice but I keep making a mistake in the integration. Can someone show me how it should look? So I can fix my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S$ is the solution to geometric brownian motion SDE:
\begin{equation}
dS=\mu S dt + \sigma S dW(t)
\end{equation}
then 
\begin{equation}
S=S_0e^{(\mu - \sigma^2/2)t + \sigma W(t)}
\end{equation}
Then if you take expectation
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[S(t)]=S_0e^{(\mu - \sigma^2/2)t}\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma W(t)}]
\end{equation}
Now since $W$ is a wiener process:
\begin{equation}
W(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)
\end{equation}
the expected value is the moment generating function of the normal distribution. This means
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma W(t)}]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\sigma x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2t}(x^2 - 2t\sigma x)}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\frac12\sigma^2 t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2t}(x^2 - 2t\sigma x + \sigma^2t^2)}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\frac12\sigma^2 t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2t}(x-\sigma t)^2}dx=e^{\frac12\sigma^2 t}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12y^2}dy=e^{\frac12\sigma^2 t}
\end{equation}
if you substitute
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[S(t)]=S_0e^{\mu t}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you, I had made minor errors but this has cleared them up for me.